# Is it better to pass a DataView in a Viewstate or Session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a DataView that will probably never have more then 2000 records.
So should I use a Session or a ViewState to pass it?  I have to load it in one routine and use it in another. But these are call one another the other.
When I get the correct answer how do you then get it out of either the ViewState or Session?

Comment: where you want to manage the state client side or server side? Anyways if you want session variable that will persist from the moment they hit and browser close use session state. ViewState is the variable that holds the current state of the page, which is held in a hidden field in the page (used frequently)

Comment: That's a *lot* of data. If you put it in ViewState you will kill the browser. If you put it in Session you will kill the server. Your only sensible option with such a large data set is to write it to the database, then read it back out in the next page.

Comment: A lot will depend on how and what this data is used for.  Generally speaking, you should avoid using Session & Viewstate.  Web applications are disconnected and should be treated as such.  if you feel you have the need to store a 2000 record data table to update later, you may need to rethink your design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you will use the information within the same page, I'll say, use ViewState. The difference of both are:

**Session State** contains information that is pertaining to a specific session (by a particular client/browser/machine) with the server. It's a way to track what the user is doing on the site.. across multiple pages...amid the statelessness of the Web. e.g. the contents of a particular user's shopping cart is session data. Cookies can be used for session state.

```
Session["UserName"] = "Test";
```

On other pages, you can get the user name out of Session with the following codes:

```
string UserName = (string)Session["UserName"];
```

**View State** on the other hand is information specific to particular web page. It is stored in a hidden field so that it isn't visible to the user. It is used to maintain the user's illusion that the page remembers what he did on it the last time - dont give him a clean page every time he posts back.

```
ViewState["color"] = "red";

string strColor;
strColor =(string)ViewState["color"];
```